# Trying to implement Google Sign-In for a website, but the button is not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm trying to implement the standard Google Sign-In option on a website, as they suggest here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/.

As a beginning, I thought I'd just follow the basic instructions (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) and I'm using nothing more than their sample code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(obviously with the client id replaced by the one generated from their developer console for my site).  I entered the site IP address as a valid JavaScript origin when creating the Client ID, as described.  However, the login button doesn't even appear.

I feel like an idiot, because I'm sure there's some obvious step that I'm missing, but I just haven't been able to figure it out.  Any recommendations?

Comment: I suggest you read this article - http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php, it's good for beginners because it provides a simple login system which you can copy-paste and play with.

Comment: I have exact the same problem. It won't show up!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Might be too late to respond, but here is the solution.

Remove "async defer" from loading platorm.js.

Comment: This worked for me. Might be too late to expect a reply, but this probably works because platform.js expects function signOn() to be declared?

Comment: It's been years, but I figured I should accept this so that it would get closed out.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was solved by disabling Adblock. It prevents the script from loading properly.

Answer (score 1):

> The Google Sign in API works only on a running web server. You will not be able to see the `Sign in` button if you are directly opening the file.

Quoted from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48497385/7132886)

I was facing the same problem. Running it on a xampp server worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code worked for me. To get it to work:

1. Create a temporary folder and add a file index.html
2. Edit index.html and paste the full contents of your script into it
3. Start a Web server on localhost, for my test, I used the python built-in web server, `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`
4. Navigate to the web server running on http://localhost:8000

When running your code, I see the button render in blue. A few things worth trying if this still doesn't work for you:

- See if the content renders in another browser, I prefer and tested in Chrome
- Use the browser's developer console to get information about JavaScript errors
- Ensure that you have properly configured the client that you set up in the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. The problem is that I wanted to add it using javascript, though it seems the google API disallows that.

The solution for me was to add the `div` to my index.html file and set it to `display: none;`. Then I can move it around and reshow it when I need it.