# Google Sign In Button Won't Render

Tags: google-chrome, google-signin

I'm trying to make a sign in page for my web application and I followed the steps on this website:https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in
but the google sign in button won't show up, it's just a blank screen but I see that the google icon shows up and fades so it is connecting to google. 
this is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google SignIn</title>
   <!-- Bootstrap CDN: Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <!-- Google Sign In Client ID -->
   <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="**MY GOOGLE CLIENT ID**">
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
   <!-- Jquery -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
       .g-signin2{
           margin-left:500px;
           margin-top:200px;
       }   
        .data{
            display:none;
        }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <div class="data">
        <p>Profile Details</p>
        <img id="pic" class="img-circle" width="100" height="100"/>
        <p>Email Address</p>
        <p id="email" class="alert alert-danger"></p>
        <button onclick="signOut()" class="btn btn-danger">SignOut</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console (ctrl + shift + I)?

Comment: actually i do have this error:
"Invalid cookiePolicy"
stack
:
"gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError

Answer (score 1):

The Google Sign in API works only on a running web server. You will not be able to see the `Sign in` button if you are directly opening the file.